# Parse String by DateTimeFormatter.forPattern

Tags: java, parsing, datetime, jodatime

I have a String:

```
Sun May 15 00:00:00 IST 2011
```

Now if I want to parse it into joda DateTime by the pattern:

```
EEE MMM dd 00:00:00 z yyyy
```

I am getting:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "Sun May 15 00:00:00 IST 2011" is malformed at " 00:00:00 IST 2011"
```

But the SimpleDateFormat with the same pattern can parse that String to java.util.Date. What I am doing wrong?

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: are you sure you didn't specify `HH:mm:ss` when using `SimpleDateFormat`?

Comment: @asgs yes the pattern is same for both of the formatter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JODA does not support parsing of time zone names.

From the [API documentation](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html):

Zone names: Time zone names ('z') cannot be parsed.

Comment: thanks. So to parse that String should I parse it into Date by SimpleDateFormat and then create an instance of DateTime from that Date?

Comment: The best approach would probably be to change the format of your time stamp string. THe problem is that the time zone names are ambiguous, e.g. "IST" being used for Irish Summer Time, Israel Standard Time and Indian Standard Time. Even if you use java.util.SimpleDateFromat, you cannot be sure that you really get what you expect.